# форма комментария на Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Привет,

У меня есть форма комментария, но она отображается только для залогиняных.
Как сделать ее доступной и для не залогиняных пользователей, потому что сейчас пишет "You must be logged in to post a comment."

Заранее спасибо

Comment: В админке на странице настроек разрешите комментарии от неавторизованных пользователей (Настройки -> обсуждение. Убрать галочку с пункта "Пользователи должны быть зарегистрированы и авторизованы для комментирования.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключить в настройках обсуждения.

[image]

Comment: Не знаю как я упустил такой момент. Но все теперь заработало) спасибо